# Execute Custom Function on `poetry build`

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) to manage a python package's dependencies and automate the build and release process.
Part of the release pipeline is [generating](https://pyuavcan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pyuavcan.dsdl.html#pyuavcan.dsdl.compile) a subpackage, to be included in the release (sdist/wheel). [Setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html) had Distutils' [`build_py` hook](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/extending.html#integrating-new-commands), but I don't find anything comparable in Poetry.

Is there a way to add custom function hooks to `poetry build`?